# How can I add display only cifilter on live video capture in swift?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, video-capture, cifilter

I am working on a functionality where I need to create a video recorder. I want to display cifilter on live capture. Yes it is possible to add filter on live capture and save it using this  code:

```
 func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        connection.videoOrientation = orientation
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        
        let comicEffect = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
        
        let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        let cameraImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
        
        comicEffect!.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        
        let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(comicEffect!.outputImage!, from: cameraImage.extent)!
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let filteredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            self.filteredImage.image = filteredImage
        }
    }
```

But my requirement is different. I want to display only the filters on video capture. The filter applied should be displayed to user only at capture time and the video should not be saved with filters. I want captured video to be saved without any filter. I am able to capture video using AVFoundation as:

```
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    var activeInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
        //Setup 
       previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = camPreview.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        camPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

//MARK:- Camera Session
    func startSession() {
    
        if !captureSession.isRunning {
            videoQueue().async {
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }

    func stopSession() {
        if captureSession.isRunning {
            videoQueue().async {
                self.captureSession.stopRunning()
            }
        }
    }

    func videoQueue() -> DispatchQueue {
        return DispatchQueue.main
    }
  ///Get output  after stop recording
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    
        if (error != nil) {
        
            print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        
        } else {
        
            let videoRecorded = outputURL! as URL
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let savedVDOAsset = AVAsset(url: videoRecorded)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: savedVDOAsset)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    playerController.player = player
    self.present(playerController, animated: true, completion: {
        playerController.player!.play()
    })
            }
        }
    }
```

I mean I can do both things(To capture a video and to display filter on video) differently. But can't find how to do both things at the same time.
Again: I don't want to save video with filters. Filters are only to display. And at the same time video need to be captured and saved.
How can I do this? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with video capture, but I'll try to answer anyway.

To display (live) the video with filter, you should render the output of the CIFilter in a MTKView. In short, you create a CIImage with a filter and ask the MTKView to draw itself using that image, each time that captureOutput is called (every frame).

You can find how to stream the live camera feed in a MTKView in this tutorial: https://betterprogramming.pub/using-cifilters-metal-to-make-a-custom-camera-in-ios-c76134993316

Be aware there could be some issues with scaling your frames into the MTKView drawable, in that case refer to this thread:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909846/mtkview-displaying-camera-feed-with-lower-resolution-than-avcapturevideopreviewl)

Also, in the thread, you can find some sample code taken from a project where I do exactly what I just wrote.